# Laravel: WHY? All my seeding entries are blank if my model has a __construct function?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, models, seeding

I have added __construct functions to some of my models which causes the seeding to give blank entries. I know this is the issue as removing the construct function makes the seeding work just fine.

Presumably I am over-ridding something in the Eloquent construct function?

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your constructor into:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = array()) {
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    // here the rest of your code
}
```

to run Eloquent constructor

Comment: Thanks very much. Knew it had to be something like that!

Answer (score 2):

Call `parent::__construct($attributes);` before your custom constructor code. Remember to put `$attributes=[]` in your own constructor parameters.